# Elasticsearch: Having document score equal number of hits in field

Tags: elasticsearch, scoring

Using elasticsearch, I'm searching through an index on a field that typically has a large amount of text and I simply want to know the number of times the query was matched per document. Anyone know of a good way to do this? I'd like to do it through the score value if possible. So for example, if I searched "fox" on "the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy fox", I'd get something that includes:

"_score" : 2.0

Comment: Looks like the explain query option will take care of this.

{
    "explain": true,
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
    }
}. The term frequency in the result will give you the number of hits per document. Here's the link: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-explain.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default scoring model also account this into picture , but then this is not the only thing accounts.
What you are looking for is called term frequency.
The default scoring model is based on TF-IDF ( Term frequency and inverse document frequency) and also field length.
You can read more about it [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/relevance-intro.html).

Now coming back to your requirement , you can use the [scripting module](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-advanced-scripting.html) and [function score query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html)

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "field": "fox"
        }
      },
      "boost_mode": "replace",
      "functions": [
        {
          "script_score": {
            "script": "_index['field']['fox'].tf()"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```